# VBA copy paste loop and go to next available cell

Tags: excel, vba

i need to copy values from a cell in column b to 4 cells in column d and then jump down to the next cell in b and copy the value to the next 4 cells in column d.

I tried this code

```
Sub copytest() 
    Dim i As Long
    For i = 1 To 394 ' i have a total of 394 cells 
        Range("B" & i).Copy Range("d1:d4") 
    Next i 
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

assuming column D is empty, try this

```
Sub copytest()
    Dim i As Long
    For i = 1 To 394 ' i have a total of 394 cells
       Range("B" & i).Copy Cells(Rows.Count, "D").End(xlUp).Offset(1).Resize(4) ' copy column B cirrent row i cell to column D four cells after last not empty one
    Next i
    Range("D1").Delete xlUp' delete D1 cell, since previous code left it empty
End Sub
```